# Would it be good practice to separate a user entity and a user profile entity?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, single-responsibility

When designing a system that displays information about an entity (but where modification of the data is rare or restricted to few users - such as a user profile), would it make sense to have two separate classes to do this?

One for management of a user profile (logging in, changing password, modifying profile content) and another purely for the consumption of this data (a UserProfile/UserView) which can only retrieve the displayed data for the user.

1. Is this a sensible choice to make?
2. Would there be any security reasons in this style of architecture?
3. Would this violate the concept of modelling an entity as a single class? (and are there instances where this is acceptable/expected?)
4. Are there any common patterns or best practices for modelling an entity in this way?

Let's work on the assumption that this is a social media profile.

Comment: I cannot answer all of your questions, but the core answer is you don't need a mega-class that models every possible state-behavior for a given entity across all domains. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

Comment: E.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/213403/ddd-bounded-contexts-domains

Comment: That's really helpful thanks, although I guess that leads to the question, at what point is that an appropriate thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, there are several aspects to think about.

Depending on how you see the `user`, the `user`-Information could be modeled as part of the `userprofile` or the other way around:

```
user = {
         "lastname": "Doe",
         "firstname": "John",
         "id": "a972f435-5263-401a-a03b-950e9e0e29c1",
         "birthday": "1970-01-01"
       }
```

There is nothing wrong with this kind of data. If you use a backend capable of dealing with JSON, you could store it right away.

On the other hand, depending on how detailed your `user` is, it makes sense to separate `user`-data from `profile`-data; or perhaps you have the need to use different databases for different purposes: say, you have a `login`-service which serves the only purpose to `log in` users - in such a scenario it makes perfectly sense to have your `user` in one place and the `profile` in another (perhaps you are using `MongoDB` or something like that).

> Is this a sensible choice to make?

There is no *general* solution to that. It is a *rather* philosophical question without context. A nice topic for a *scholastic* discussion about architecture.

> Would there be any security reasons in this style of architecture?

Unfortunately I am no security expert to give you a detailed answer to that. You have to secure your system anyways. From a security perspective it could make sense to split between `user` and `profile` or better: `user`, `profile`, `creditcard`-data in three different databases. But that is a naive guess. There are people who are better at security than me ;)

> Would this violate the concept of modelling an entity as a single class? (and are there instances where this is acceptable/expected?)
>
> Are there any common patterns or best practices for modelling an entity in this way?

As said from the above: there are reason to handle it one way or the other. I would go with *as long as you have no reason to really split the data, keep it all together*. Look for *simple* solutions in the first place and *evolve* your system alongside with your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`User` and `UserProfile` are different entities in the same way `User` and `BankAccount` are different entities.

In the case of displaying info, each entity has the responsability of displaying it's info, although `User` can delegate part of its displaying reaponsability to its `UserProfile`.